# how to trigger esper if there are no incoming events for a given period of time

Tags: java, c#, apache-kafka, esper, nesper

I have esper processer configured to listen messages in kafka.

usually `select * from events.win:time(2 min)` will trigger all events in last 2 mins
Now, I want to trigger a notification if there are no messages in kafka for last 2 minutes.

how should I deal with it, when I write something like
 `select * from events(Ip='1.1.1.1').win:time(2 min)` 
 this will not have matching messages/events and esper is not triggering .

how should I trigger esper if events are absent in given time

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us your code - how you implemented the Kafka adapter and the Esper processer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this

```
select * from pattern [every (timer:interval(2 min) and not MyEvent)]
```

// tip: don't call your event "events", call it something useful and use uppercase

Comment: Thank you!, I figured out this a day back , what u answered is exactly right. earlier actually I tried something like `select count(*) from myEvents.win:time(1 min) having 1>count(*) ` which don't work - finally I came across the solution above mentioned .

Comment: In my actual code it is not events, I thought it could be easy for the community members to understand my question so I used that `events` . thanks for pointing it